# Is TAPI in the WinRT API?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, tapi

I've not had a chance to play with WinRT yet. I just wondered whether anyone knew if TAPI is part of the WinRT API now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to MS currently TAPI is not part of WinRT although the information is preliminary  and rather likely to change over time... for details see  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464945%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

To answer your specific question, the answer is no.  Better than asking here for this kind of question is looking at the docs.  The list of APIs available from Metro style applications can be found in the [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229578%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) section of [dev.windows.com](http://dev.windows.com).